# Can an expected value (mean) be higher than the values used to create it?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have this distribution, where '$x_i$' is shorthand for $X=i$, where $i=0,1,2,3,4$ and where $X$ is a random variable with possible values $0,1,2,3,4$

$$
P(x_0) = 0.2 \\
P(x_1) = 0.25 \\
P(x_2) = 0.3 \\
P(x_3) = 0.15 \\
P(x_4) = 0.1
$$

Using the [Expected Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) formula:

$$
\mu = (0)0.2 + (1)0.25 + (2)0.3 + (3)0.15 + (4)0.1 \\
\mu = 1.7
$$

How does this make sense? How can the expected value be LARGER than any probability in my distribution? Am I using the wrong formula?

Comment: You may be interested in the related [Probabilistic Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_method).

Comment: In your table, you write $P(x_n)$, but it appears you mean $P(x=n)$. Is that correct?

Comment: Expected value $E=\sum_{j=1}^k p_j x_j$ is the inner-product of two vectors: a vector of values $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_k)$ and a vector of probabilities. $(p_1,\ldots,p_k)$. You can make $E$ as small or as large as you want by fixing $p$ and playing with $x$, or vice-versa. However, by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $|E| \le \|x\|_\infty := \max_j |x_j|$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The expected value cannot be larger than all of the possible **values**, but it can certainly be larger than any of the **probabilities**. If you roll a fair die, each of the possible values ($1,2,3,4,5$, and $6$) occurs with probability $\frac16$, so the expected value is $$(1)\frac16+(2)\frac16+(3)\frac16+(4)\frac16+(5)\frac16+(6)\frac16=3.5\;,$$ far bigger than $\frac16$.

Now imagine that the die has a $6$ on every face. The probability that it comes up $6$ is $1$, and the expected value is clearly $6$: you can’t get anything else!

The expected value can be thought of as the long run average value of the possible values, each of them weighted by its probability of occurrence; in principle it can be anywhere between the smallest possible value and the largest possible value. It is affected by the probabilities **only** to the extent that they affect the weighting of the possible values.

Comment: So the 1.7 is right? Awesome :) Thanks

Comment: I have a question regarding the example you have given. Does expected value make any sense when all the probabilities are the same? I understand that if the probabilities of getting each number was different, then we would be taking weighted averages. But, for example, in the answer: what do I infer from 3.5?

Comment: @user93868: That if you roll a fair die many times, the average roll will be very close to $3.5$.

Comment: @Brian, thanks!

Comment: @user93868: You’re welcome!

Comment: Just one more thing, can you tell me if my understanding is correct: 1) if the probabilities are different, then the expected value is close to the number were will get (in your die with only 6 example), but 2) if all possible events have equal chance of happening, expected value is not the value we get, but the average of all possible values. Is this right?

Comment: @user93868: Not quite. In general the expected value need not be a possible value; however, if, for instance, you had a fair die with a $1$ on one face and $6$ on each of the other five faces, the expected value would be $\frac16\cdot1+\frac56\cdot6=\frac{31}6$, much closer to $6$ than to $1$. The probabilities are in effect weights: the more likely an outcome is, the more heavily it influences the expected value.

Answer (score 4):

The expectation of your distribution is exactly
$$ 0.2 x_0 + 0.25 x_1 + 0.3 x_2 + 0.15 x_3 + 0.1 x_4. $$
According to the frequentist interpretation, the expected value is the value that you get when you perform a large number of experiments and compute the average. So if for example your random variable is constant, say always equal to $10$, then the expectation is $10$. There's no problem with the expectation being bigger than $1$. However, since the expectation is a weighted average of the values of the random variable, it always lies between the *minimal* value and the *maximal* value. So if your random variable always gets a value betewen $3$ and $7$, then the expectation is also going to be between $3$ and $7$.

Answer (score 1):

Expected value $E=\sum_{j=1}^k p_j x_j$ is the inner-product of two vectors: a vector of values $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_k)$ and a vector of probabilities. $(p_1,\ldots,p_k)$. You can make $E$ as small or as large as you want by fixing $p$ and playing with $x$, or vice-versa. However, by the *Cauchy-Schwarz inequality* for vectors in $\mathbb R^k$, we have the bound $|E| \le \|x\|_\infty\|p\|_1 = \|x\|_\infty := \max_j |x_j|$.